# Вордпресс Как убрать рамку вокруг поста на отдельной странце

Tags: css, wordpress, border

Ворпресс ShootingStar Theme. Шаблон отдельной страницы [Full Width Page](http://shootingstar.tomastoman.com/full-width-page/)
Сделал белый фон. Подскажите, как убрать серую рамку вокруг поста только для шаблона этой страницы.
Желательно добавлением отдельного css к странице.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Например вот так:

```
div.entry-content {
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Может быть надо будет определить на какой именно странице вы хотите удалить рамки.
Может быть придется использовать `!important` перед точкой с запятой...

Answer (score 1):

Ответ @Michael правильный, но для того, чтобы это работало только "для шаблона этой страницы" надо вот так:

```
.page-template-template-full-width .entry-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```